# Regex expression to extra a fields

Tags: python, regex

Give the string below:

```
';\n;20121110_160816\n;www.google.com\n\n; Test\na=5\n\nend\n'
```

What is the regex to parse the string as the following fields? :

```
;\n
;20121110_160816\n
;www.google.com\n
; Test\n
```

My initial failed attempt is below:

```
import re
m = re.search(';.+?\\n', mystr)
```

outputting:

```
m.group()
';20121110_160816\n'
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't have experience with regexes in Python, but I do know regexes in general, and I can tell you that you probably want .*? rather than .+? ... that is, if you want to also match the "empty" `;\n`. + requires one or more characters; * is zero or more.

Comment: Have you tried `s.split(';')` ?

Comment: `m = re.findall(r';.*?\n', mystr)`

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, I need regex for this problem. Thanks tough.

Comment: @Prince, that produces what I want, thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use `split()`? I don't see the need for a regex here...

Comment: Tim, a modified version of this regex goes to PLY's lexer. I don't know if this can be done with split().

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.findall('(;.*)\n', s)
```

expression walk-through:

1. your item starts with a ";" -> ';
2. followed by practical any sign in any quantities -> ".*" the "."=any sign "*"=0-infinite times
3. it ends with a newline -> "\n"
4. for readability i put the repetition-grp into parenthesis

but in this case you should also consider:

s.split(), which splits automatically at newlines if not suplemented with an argument.

**update** - commenting your comment ;-)

I'm not sure if i really understand your question yobout the question mark. But in general the asterisks, question marks and plus signs are quantifiers. Similar to the ,   and -keys they don't have a meaning in themselves and are alone mostly worthless. But in combination with other key/chars they modify the behaviour of them, or in case of the quantufiers specify if and/or how many times the preceding char/group should be repeated.

Comment: r';.*?\n' produces the exact output, or r';.*\n'
without question mark; though not sure the role "?" here.

Comment: feel free to add this comment to your question as a follow up.